# ¿Cómo hago rotar una imagen en php?

Tags: php, android, imagen

Estoy haciendo un app en `Android` que envía una imagen al servidor. La imagen es sacada de la galería. El problema es que la imagen que tomo desde la cámara está en vertical y al verla en el servidor se pone en modo horizontal. Creo que el problema es del web service que está hecho en `php`.

Por eso, quisiera saber si hay manera de rotar la imagen que es leída con:

```
$image = base64_decode($image);
```

y lo guarda con

```
file_put_contents($path, $image);
```

**Este es el codigo completo del php**

```
<?php

require("conexion.php");

$image =$_REQUEST['image'];
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$nick = $_REQUEST['nick'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$edad = $_REQUEST['edad'];
$distrito =$_REQUEST['distrito'];
$descripcion =$_REQUEST['descripcion'];
$interes =$_REQUEST['interes'];



    $now=DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u',microtime(true));
    $id=$now->format('YmdHisu');

$foto1 = "$id.jpg";

$mensaje="registro_insertado";

//verificando si existe usuario
$consultaUser = "SELECT * FROM proveedor WHERE User='$user'";
$result = mysql_query($consultaUser);
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($user == $fila['User']){
        $mensaje="user_existe";
    }
}

//verificando si existe nick
$consultaNick = "SELECT * FROM proveedor WHERE Nick='$nick'";
$result2 = mysql_query($consultaNick);
while ($fila2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    if($nick == $fila2['Nick']){
        $mensaje="nick_existe";
    }
}

if($mensaje=="registro_insertado"){

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO proveedor (User,Password,Nick,Email,Distritos,Edad,Foto1,Descripcion,Intereses) VALUES ('$user','$password','$nick','$email','$distrito','$edad','$foto1','$descripcion','$interes')";

    mysql_query($consulta);

    $path="../imagenes/$id.jpg";

    $image = base64_decode($image);

    if(file_put_contents($path,$image) != false){

        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        $msg = "uploaded_success";
        $arr = array('msg' => $msg , 'id' => $id);
        echo json_encode($arr);

    }else{

        $msg = "uploaded_failed";
        $arr = array('msg' => $msg , 'id' => "");
        echo json_encode($arr);

    }

}else{
    $arr = array('msg' => $mensaje , 'id' => "");
    echo json_encode($arr);
}


?>
```

**Este es el codigo en Android**

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity{

private final String TAG =this.getClass().getName();

Button btnreg;
Button btncancel;
EditText edUser,edPassword,edPassword2,edNick,edEmail,edEdad,edDescripcion;
ImageView ivCamera,ivGallery,ivImage;
Spinner spinnerDistrito,spinnerInteres;
CameraPhoto cameraPhoto;
GalleryPhoto galleryPhoto;

final int CAMERA_REQUEST=13323;
final int GALLERY_REQUEST=22131;

String selectedPhoto="";

String idProveedor;
String msg;

DatabaseReference mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register2);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},1);
            }
        }

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
            }
        }

        cameraPhoto=new CameraPhoto(getApplicationContext());
        galleryPhoto=new GalleryPhoto(getApplicationContext());

        ivCamera=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivCamera);
        ivGallery=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivGallery);
        ivImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivimage);
        btncancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar2);
        btnreg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister2);
        edUser=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_user2);
        edPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        edPassword2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password2);
        edNick=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_nick2);
        edEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email2);
        edEdad=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_edad2);
        edDescripcion=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_descripcion);
        spinnerInteres=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_Interes);

        spinnerDistrito=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerDistrito2);

    String[] distritos = {"Ancón","Ate","Barranco","Breña","Carabayllo","Chaclacayo", "Chorrillos", "Cieneguilla"
            , "Comas", "El Agustino", "Independencia (Lima)", "Jesús María", "La Molina", "La Victoria", "Lima", "Lince",
            "Los Olivos", "Lurigancho-Chosica", "Lurín", "Magdalena del Mar", "Miraflores", "Pachacámac",
            "Pucusana", "Pueblo Libre", "Puente Piedra", "Punta Hermosa", "Punta Negra", "Rímac", "San Bartolo", "San Borja",
            "San Isidro", "San Juan de Lurigancho", "San Juan de Miraflores", "San Luis", "San Martín de Porres", "San Miguel",
            "Santa Anita", "Santa María del Mar", "Santa Rosa (Lima)", "Santiago de Surco", "Villa El Salvador", "Villa María del Triunfo"};

    String[] intereses = {"Diversión","Diversión y apoyo económico","Relación abierta"};

    spinnerDistrito.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, distritos));
    spinnerInteres.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,intereses));

        ivCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent(),CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    cameraPhoto.addToGallery();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something Wrong while taking photos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        ivGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent(),GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });


    btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {


                     String edad=edEdad.getText().toString();
                     final String user=edUser.getText().toString();
                     String pass=edPassword.getText().toString();
                     String pass2=edPassword2.getText().toString();
                     String nick=edNick.getText().toString();
                     final String email=edEmail.getText().toString();
                     String descripcion=edDescripcion.getText().toString();
                     String interes=spinnerInteres.getSelectedItem().toString();
                     String distrito=spinnerDistrito.getSelectedItem().toString();


                    if(!user.equals("") && !pass.equals("") && !pass2.equals("") && !nick.equals("") && !email.equals("") && !edad.equals("")  && !descripcion.equals("") && !interes.equals("")){
                        if(pass.equals(pass2)){
                            if(!selectedPhoto.equals("") || selectedPhoto!=null){


                                Bitmap bitmap=ImageLoader.init().from(selectedPhoto).getBitmap();
                                //bitmap=redimensionarImagenMaximo(bitmap,512,512);


                                String encodedImage= ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);
                                Log.d(TAG,encodedImage);

                                HashMap<String,String> postData=new HashMap<String, String>();

                                postData.put("image",encodedImage);
                                postData.put("user",user);
                                postData.put("password",pass);
                                postData.put("nick",nick);
                                postData.put("email",email);
                                postData.put("edad",edad);
                                postData.put("distrito",distrito);
                                postData.put("descripcion",descripcion);
                                postData.put("interes",interes);

                                PostResponseAsyncTask task=new PostResponseAsyncTask(Register.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void processFinish(String s) {
                                        Log.d("JSON",s);
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(s);
                                            idProveedor = jsonObject.getString("id");
                                            msg = jsonObject.getString("msg");
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        if(msg.equals("uploaded_success")){
                                            mDatabase.child("Proveedores").child("P"+idProveedor).setValue(new User(user,email));
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Member registrado exitosamente",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);

                                        }else if(msg.equals("user_existe")){
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El Usuario ya existe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }else if(msg.equals("nick_existe")){
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El Nick ya existe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                task.execute("http://blackmate.esy.es/blackmateapp/insertarProveedor.php");
                                task.setEachExceptionsHandler(new EachExceptionsHandler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void handleIOException(IOException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cannot Connect to Server.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void handleMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"URL Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void handleProtocolException(ProtocolException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Protocol Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void handleUnsupportedEncodingException(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Encoding Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });






                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No haz seleccionado imagen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Las Contraseñas no coinciden",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Faltan datos por completar",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No haz seleccionado imagen",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


        btncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


}

public Bitmap redimensionarImagenMaximo(Bitmap mBitmap, float newWidth, float newHeigth){
    //Redimensionamos
    int width = mBitmap.getWidth();
    int height = mBitmap.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeigth) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST){
            String photoPath= cameraPhoto.getPhotoPath();
            selectedPhoto=photoPath;
            Bitmap bitmap;


            try {
                bitmap= ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512,512).getBitmap();

                File imageFile = new File(photoPath);
                ExifInterface exif = null;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                int rotate = 360;
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                }


                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,512,512,true);
                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap , 0, 0, scaledBitmap .getWidth(), scaledBitmap .getHeight(), matrix, true);

                ivImage.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something Wrong while loading photos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Log.d(TAG,photoPath);
        }else if(requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST){
                Uri uri=data.getData();
                galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(uri);
                String photoPath=galleryPhoto.getPath();
                selectedPhoto=photoPath;
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap= ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512,512).getBitmap();

                File imageFile = new File(photoPath);
                ExifInterface exif = null;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                int rotate = 360;
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                }


                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,512,512,true);
                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap , 0, 0, scaledBitmap .getWidth(), scaledBitmap .getHeight(), matrix, true);

                ivImage.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something Wrong while choosing photos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

pd: soy la misma persona (Jair Vasquez)

Comment: En php puedes usar las librerías de manipulación de imágenes GD, Gmagick o ImageMagick (entre otras). No obstante, si publicas el código que ya tienes, es posible que podamos ayudarte de forma más específica.

Comment: yo tengo una posible solución a tu problema pero desde el codigo android, me gustaria que subieras el código donde mandas a subir la imagen

Comment: Si, he hecho como dicen pero no da resultado

Answer (score 0):

```
//Cargar la imgen
$imagenOrigen= imagecreatefromjpeg('ruta/a/test.jpg'); 

// Rotar la imagen
$rotada = imagerotate($imagenOrigen, $grados, 0);

//Guardala
file_put_contents("nuevaImagen.jpg",$rotada );
```

Mira la función `imagerotate`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Mas info de `imagecreatefromXXXX`: http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=imagecreatefromjpg&lang=es&scope=404quickref

Answer (score 0):

Para que no tengas que guardar la imagen, leerla, rotarla y después volverla a guardar, puedes usar el método `imagecreatefromstring` y hacer lo siguiente:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($image));
$image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
imagepng($image, $path);
```

> Nota: He rotado la imagen `90º`, dependiendo de tus necesidades quizás necesites rotarla `-90º`.

Para guardar la imagen debes usar [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagepng.php) o [imagejpg](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagejpeg.php) (en el ejemplo he guardado la imagen como `PNG`).

**EDIT:** Este es tu código con el cambio para rotar la imagen antes de guardarla para que notes dónde es que debes realizar el cambio:

```
if ($mensaje == "registro_insertado") {

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO proveedor (User, Password, Nick, Email, Distritos, Edad, Foto1, Descripcion, Intereses) VALUES ('$user', '$password', '$nick', '$email', '$distrito', '$edad', '$foto1', '$descripcion', '$interes')";
    mysql_query($consulta);
    $path = "../imagenes/$id.jpg";

    $image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($image));
    $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);

    if (imagepng($image, $path) != false) {

        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        $msg = "uploaded_success";
        $arr = array('msg' => $msg , 'id' => $id);
        echo json_encode($arr);

    } else {

        $msg = "uploaded_failed";
        $arr = array('msg' => $msg , 'id' => "");
        echo json_encode($arr);

    }

} else {

    $arr = array('msg' => $mensaje , 'id' => "");   
    echo json_encode($arr);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas rotar una imagen desde PHP puedes utilizar la funcion que viene por defecto en el lenguaje **imagerotate** , la cual rota una imagen usando el angulo dado, un ejemplo de esto:

```
  <?php
    // Archivo y rotación
    $nombre_archivo = 'prueba.jpg';
    $grados = 180;

    // Tipo de contenido
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

   // Cargar
   $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($nombre_archivo);

   // Rotar
   $rotar = imagerotate($origen, $grados, 0);

   // Imprimir
   imagejpeg($rotar);

   // Liberar la memoria
   imagedestroy($origen);
   imagedestroy($rotar);
 ?>
```

Observa este link: [Rotar Imagen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810501/php-get-base64-img-string-decode-and-save-as-jpg-resulting-empty-image). Pudiera ayudarte.
La documentacion en PHP esta en: [PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagerotate.php)

Saludos!

Comment: Pero si quiero guardar la imagen rotada en el servidor?

Comment: Creo que te convendría entonces rotarlo en java desde la aplicación móvil en la lectura y que llegue de la forma que deseas a PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo si deseas rotar una imagen lo mas recomendable que uses css `jQuery` `JavaScript` ya sé que la respuesta que daré no es de `php` pero espero que siquiera te ayude de algo en estilo `css`:

```
#miImagen {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Comment: El OP indica quiere manipular la orientación de la imagen que envía desde su aplicativo Android a su servicio web.